# IIS URL Rewrite rules when query params exist, but no root file

Tags: regex, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a web application being served up by IIS to `example.com/mywebapp`. The default file is `index.html`, so when someone loads `example.com/mywebapp` - index.html is what is actually loaded (pretty standard behavior). If someone requests the webapp with query params, but no file name (ie `example.com/mywebapp/?params=123`) the URL seems to get automatically "corrected" to `example.com/mywebapp?params=123` - which is interpreted by IIS as a file, `mywebapp` at the root level of the webserver `example.com`... and this doesn't exist.

Is it possible to use a web.config file in the `mywebapp` directory and leverage Rewrite or Redirect rules so that `example.com/mywebapp/?params=123` becomes `example.com/mywebapp/index.html?params=123` --- but ONLY when URL params are present?

Comment: You should go after "the URL seems to get automatically "corrected" to". Use browser developer tools and IIS failed request tracing together to learn what exactly happened.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following rule:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite Params to Index" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This is my test result:

[image]